# Java data structure choice

Tags: java, arraylist

Long story short I want to be able to use some kind of data structure which can retrieve values based on x and y coordinates of an object, although that value(space) can hold multiple objects. Think of a 2d map with tiles that can contain multiple objects. I initially thought to create a 2d array that stores arraylists, but apparently Java doesn't allow that. I would also like to be able to iterate through each element of the structure based on pre-defined x and y bounds. Where should I go from here?

Edit: would creating a new object with an arraylist variable and storing that object in the 2d array be a reasonable work-around?

Comment: You could go `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, Collection<Object>>`? So your first key could be an x or y then the second would be the coordinate you didn't choose for the first key.

Comment: @SamYonnou Can you explain why a sorted map would be better for iterating the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java allows to define 2d array such but it will have multiple limitations : it uses integer as indexes, which could be limiting about your requirement : no floating number for `x` and `y`, max index to `2147483647`, and some others.
You could define something like :

```
MyObjects[][] myObjects = new MyObjects[50][200];
```

As alternative, you could use a structure `Map<XYCoord, List<MyObject>>` where `XYCoord` is a custom class that defines a coordinate : `x` and `y` and overrides `equals()` and `hashCode()` by relying on these two fields such as :

```
public class XYCoord {

    private int x;
    private int y;

    public XYCoord(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + x;
        result = prime * result + y;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (!(obj instanceof XYCoord))
            return false;

        XYCoord other = (XYCoord) obj;
        if (x == other.x && y == other.y)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

}
```

You could so use it such as :

```
// create the map
Map<XYCoord, List<MyObject>> objectsOnThePlan = new HashMap<>();

// populate it 
objectsOnThePlan.put(new XYCoord(1O, 30), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(fooObj, fooObj2, fooObj3)));
objectsOnThePlan.put(new XYCoord(40, 20), new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(barObj, barObj2, barObj3)));  

// retrieve List from a specific coordinate
List<MyObject> listFrom10x30y = objectsOnThePlan.get(new XYCoord(10, 30));
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use a Map with a Point object for your X and Y coordinates as the key and an ArrayList as the value?

Answer (score 0):

Java does allow you to create a 2 dimensional array of ArrayLists like so:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Then you can simply add rows as you so please:

```
for (i=0; i<10; i++){
     mainArrayList.add(new ArrayList<String>());
}
```

Then you can work with x, y coordinates like so:

```
// Returns the ArrayList being stored at coordinate x, y. 
objectsAtCoordinate = mainArrayList.get(x).get(y)
```